# Resources for different tablets android

Tags: android, resources, resolution, tablet, hdpi

I need to put different resources for two Samsung tablets in my application.
600x1024 (Samsung Galaxy Tab 7in)
800x1280 (Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 in)
So i created two different folders **drawable-port**(for 7 in) & **drawable-large-port**(for 8.9in)in res folder but both the devices are picking the resources from **drawable-large-port** folder.

when i run getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout for both the devices output comes out to be 
SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE

so what should be the folder names so that both the devices pick the resources from different folders.

Thanks 
Narinder

Comment: If both devices return the same configuration, then they will always pick resources from the same folder - nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

The two devices are both **LARGE** screens, so in this case they are both picking up the same resource when they look in your drawable folders. They will always go to **drawable-large-port** for portrait and **drawable-large-land** for landscape.

You can add to this functionality by creating different layouts for the two devices, that use the drawables in **drawable-large-port** in different ways to take advantage of the different size of screen. 
You can define different sizes as below for your layouts:

```
res/layout-sw600dp/   // For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/   // For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

You can read more about dealing with different sized screens/devices at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @richard: ok i will use different layouts but how can i use different resources if both layout are going to pick resources from drawable-large-port?

Comment: This shouldn't matter - the resources should be correctly sized for both devices in terms of dpi, so altering layouts should suffice

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the width of screen using:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    System.out.println("width :: "+width);
    System.out.println("height :: "+height);
```

Then you can set Drawable, using width as:

```
if(width == 600)
    // set drawable-1
else if(width == 800)
    // set drawable-2
```

Answer (score 0):

The better result put the following in the drawables

---------------- for Phones ------------------------

drawable-ldpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-hdpi

----------------- for 7 inch tablets ----------------

drawable-large-mdpi

drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)

---------------- for 10 inch tablets ----------------

drawable-xlarge-mdpi